# How to update nginx?

Tags: nginx, update

I try to update nginx but it tells me the last version is 1.2.1:

```
root@localhost:~# aptitude install nginx
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.

root@localhost:~# nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.2.1
root@localhost:~# aptitude update
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release.gpg
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
40% [Working]W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages: 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/universe/binary-amd64/Packages: 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages: 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages: 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages: 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Couldn't rebuild package cache

root@localhost:~# aptitude upgrade
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.

root@localhost:~#
```

It's far away from the latest version. How to update nginx to version 1.6 or 1.7?

Comment: You might get better help at http://superuser.com

Comment: You are using an end-of-life version of Ubuntu. Update first to a supported version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, don't you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Telling you how to do basic tasks is not the purpose of this site.

Comment: @JavaRunner This might help you out with upgrading Ubuntu.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

This is the latest version that has been released into the repositories you are using. Versions are held back intentionally until they have been verified for compatibility.

If you want to bypass this, you'll need to install it manually by downloading the available binaries or compiling it yourself.